# How can I calculate number of outgoing requests per second?

Tags: http, go

I'm writing a go program which will make thousands of `http.Get` requests, concurrently, using goroutines.  This will be a long running process and I am going to add an admin feature to it that will list certain stats about the process.

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to calculate the number of requests per second I'm making.  I've come up with a few possible solutions:

1. Store a counter and have a timer that executes every few seconds that calculates the requests/second, then resets the counter.  I'm worried about doing this in a thread safe way.  If I use a mutex before accessing this counter, will I kill my performance?
2. Keep a list of timestamps for every request successfully made, then I can walk backward in the list for all timestamps within the time period I care about.  I'm worried about this list growing but maybe I can use a circular buffer.
3. Somehow keep a running moving average of my requests / sec?

What would be the best way for me to calculate the number of `http.Get` requests I'm making per second in my Go program?

Comment: If using a simple counter just use [`atomic.AddUint32`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddUint32) to increment and [`atomic.SwapUint32`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#SwapUint32) (or the …`Uint64` variants) to read and reset the counter safely. Alternatively you could use something like the [`expvar` package](https://golang.org/pkg/expvar/).

Comment: 1. Why both about a mutex while accessing network? 2. This all depends on which number you want to measure at which accuracy.

Comment: @Volker what do you mean, 'why both about a mutex'?  I would use one because many thousands of goroutines will be accessing/updating this number frequently.

Comment: http://prometheus.io is a clean idiomatic way to solve this problem, and you dont have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @JustinOpolony, I shouldn't try and speak for @Volker, but I believe he was trying to say not to worry about or be bothered by the overhead of one extra mutex (or better, a single [atomic](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddUint32) operation) compared to the synchronization and overhead required to read/write from/to a network connection (i.e. the call to `http.Get`). An extra mutex is negligible compared to that.

Comment: @JustinOpolony yes, exactly what Dave said. s/both/bother/. Sorry for the type. Latencys of register << cache << RAM << disk << network with the "<<" meaning really _much_ faster.

Comment: @Volker, disk can be slower than network.